# Replace values in and XML document in database

Tags: mysql, regex

I have an large list of XML documents stored in MySQL (yes I know...) and I'm wondering if there is an easy way to do a search and replace on the documents using just SQL.

In the example below, I'm trying to replace `mandown` (both the value & the element) with `emergkey`.

Original:

```
<clouddata>
 <type>mandown</type>
 <devicedata>
  <nomotion>0</nomotion>
  <mandown>1</mandown>
 </devicedata>
</clouddata>
```

Desired:

```
<clouddata>
 <type>emergkey</type>
 <devicedata>
  <nomotion>0</nomotion>
  <emergykey>1</emergkey>
 </devicedata>
</clouddata>
```

Note that I've simplified these examples and the real data is of various length and the elements are not necessarily ordered all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brain-dead method is

```
UPDATE yourtable SET xmlfield=REPLACE(xmlfield, 'mandown', 'emergykey');
```

or in slightly safer fashion:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET xmlfield=REPLACE(xmlfield, '<mandown>', '<emergykey>');
UPDATE yourtable SET xmlfield=REPLACE(xmlfield, '</mandown>', '</emergykey>');
UPDATE yourtable SET xmlfield=REPLACE(xmlfield, '<type>mandown</type>', '<type>emergykey</type>');
```

A truly safe method would be to pull each record into DOM and do the operations there, though this'd be slow on a large table.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT UpdateXml(UpdateXML(.., '//type', '<type>mandown</type>'), 
'//mandown', '<emergykey>1</emergkey>') as new_xml;
```

docs :- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_updatexml

(I believe it could be improved)

Answer (score 1):

> …an easy way to do a search and replace on the documents using just SQL.

I wouldn't recommend that, for the very same reasons that say that you should not use regex on HTML/XML.

It you know your data really well, and you are absolutely sure no side-effects can emerge, you could use a simple `replace()` call.

If you're unsure or the operation is too complex for string replacement, I recommend XSLT and a script that loops through your records one by one.

For your problem, this XSLT stylesheet would be all you need:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates match="node()|@*" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="devicedata/mandown">
    <emergykey><xsl:apply-templates match="node()|@*" /></emergkey>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```